# How many professional mathematicians in the world?

Tags: soft-question

What is the statistics of people who professionally use mathematics at work? How many mathematician scientists?

Comment: Mathematics on what level? A lot of people file taxes or have to count objects while at work.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5485/how-many-mathematicians-are-there).